# Dynamic Form creation - XSD XML SQL

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-mvc, xsd

I want to create a website that gives the user the ability to create/design their own dynamic forms. (c# asp MVC4). Text boxes, dropdowns, check boxes, radio buttons, etc

I was thinking of having it so, the form template created would be XML, which I would translate into HTML via xslt to present to the user.

When the form was saved/edited, I would then store the results of that form into a database table. each row would have a Form ID, Field Name, Attribute identifying the field type (Date, integer, string), Value.

My questions are these:

1. Do you think this is the right way to go about doing this? Am I
   missing something? Is there an easier way of do this?
2. Should I save the information to the database? I was thinking of just saving the
   form to XML with the submitted values in a single entry in the
   database however I think this might slow querying the data at a later date,
   as it would require parsing lots of pieces of XML.
3. Is there something out there already I can use: Any recommended
   XSD's that I could use for starters? projects?

Answer (score 2):

For what it's worth:  yes, it says here that using XML to describe forms is a good way to go about describing forms.

You may find it helpful to look at XForms (the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xforms/) is clearly written and Steven Pemberton has written an excellent [tutorial on XForms for users of HTML forms](http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/Forms/2010/xforms11-for-html-authors/)).  You may find that it's easier to do what you want with XForms than by writing your application from scratch.  Or if you do decide to write your own application from scratch, you may find that the XForms design is worth studying.

I don't think I understand your question about databases clearly enough to answer it.  Bear in mind that the cost of parsing XML stored in a database can be relatively low if you use an XQuery database (such as SQL Server, for example).

Comment: Thanks. XForms does seem promising, but I don't think it is for me. I was hoping to find an XSD that would describe every html control, and the validation detail for that control. I would then parse this with Razor in MVC to display information. Having thought about it some more, I think I am going to try to limit the scope of my requirements and stay away from XML and use a relational database to describe the form. Might need to come back to XML later if it gets too complicated, but going to pick the low hanging fruit first and see how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

CKEditor can be adapted to fulfill your requirements if you do not need drag and drop functionality.

There is also the option of using pre markers to keep the least level of detail for the form created.

I see you decided against using XML, which was a wise choice considering the sheer number of free options available now.

Comment: Where did you see he decided against XML, and how does XML conflict with free options?